# Google Adwords API - refresh token - python

Tags: python, api, google-ads-api

I am in the process of setting up with Google Adwords API. They have a fantastic guide (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start), with the exception that one of the last steps is rather vague.

I have gotten to this step, pictured here (but from the link above)

[image]

I am instructed (for Python) to put the client ID and client secret into my own configuration file. All the other languages have specific files that were added to need to be edited (such as the PHP example below).

[image]

I have been working at this for the past 3 hours, and tried googling and youtubing and reading through every piece of documentation I can find. All of them just say "add the ID and secret to your config file." I have no idea what that means, or how to do it. I've gone into my python directory and found a file named "config.py", but have no idea how to add these credentials. There is a number of scripts on github (that Google links to), one of them for generating a refresh token, like I want. I have no idea how to implement this, though.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/tree/master/examples/adwords/authentication

Thank you in advance for any insight into adding credentials to my python config file or otherwise generating a refresh token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

In short, the config file is in a directory that was not included in the instructions. It is advisable to download the entire "googleads-python-lib" directory versus just the directory "googlead".

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib

The config file (googleads.yaml) is within this "googleads-python-lib" directory. I unzipped it in my python2.7/site-packages. There are variables in this config file ready to take your authentication credentials.